# Unable to run scripts in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I was able to execute my scripts on selenium java 3.4.0 and geckodriver 0.16 but since the new update ,some of the functions are  deprecated due to which I had to change my browser configuration code and now it is not executing entirely. It doesn't execute whole script .

**Before Code** (before upgrading to java 3.5.3) :

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                "application/octet-stream;application/csv;text/csv;application/vnd.ms-excel;");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", prodDownloadPath);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(160, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(productionUrl);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Demand Summary")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//table[@class='TextObject']//tr//td[contains(text(),'16 Weeks Historical Trend')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement imageUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='QvFrame Document_CH69']/div[2]/div[2]/img"));
        Actions oAction = new Actions(driver);
        oAction.moveToElement(imageUrl);
        oAction.contextClick(imageUrl).build().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Send to Excel")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

**Latest Code (After upgrading to 3.5.3) :**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                "application/octet-stream;application/csv;text/csv;application/vnd.ms-excel;");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", prodDownloadPath);
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
        dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(160, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(productionUrl);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Demand Summary")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//table[@class='TextObject']//tr//td[contains(text(),'16 Weeks Historical Trend')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement imageUrl = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='QvFrame Document_CH80']/div[2]/div[2]/img"));
        Actions oAction = new Actions(driver);
        oAction.moveToElement(imageUrl);
        oAction.contextClick(imageUrl).build().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Send to Excel")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Previous Versions:

```
-Selenium Java 3.4.0  
-Selenium Server Standalone 3.4  
-Gecko 0.16  
-FF 46.0
```

Latest Versions:

```
-Selenium Java 3.5.3  
-Selenium Server Standalone 3.5.3  
-Gecko 0.18  
-FF 55.0.3
```

I am getting `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException:`exception during the execution of scripts. What combination of versions should I use ? or do I need to change my code or something ? Please help .

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-in-selenium-webdriver??

Comment: I have already added that line my code . I have edited my code . Please have a look

Comment: I think there is some problem with version combinations but I am unable to figure out . Can anyone suggest current working combination

Comment: what is the exception u are getting can u paste the complete log in console regarding exception

Comment: Try th change marionette with Gecko

Comment: I doubt if there is an issue with the dependency versions, since the exception reads out different. Which element line is throwing out this error. Is this is the first element interaction in the test? Is the element that you are trying to interact is completely loaded. Try adding explicit wait with conditions like element.isClickable () something like that. Also, since you are using server stand alone, java bindings are not required.

Comment: @iamsankalp89 can you elaborate in detail ?

Comment: @santhoshkumar i need more clarity on this

Comment: which line in the script throws this error?

Comment: till 'demand summary' it works after that further actions are not performed and it throws that error after that line

Answer (score 0):

Use `Implicit wait`

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or `explicit wait`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```

For reference

```
WebDriverWait Wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable (By.id("Locator")));
```

Comment: I want to click on that element as well what should i do then

Comment: There should be a method names as elementToBeClickable. Try this

Comment: there is no such method

Comment: Like this     WebDriverWait Wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable (By.id("Locator")));

Comment: Are u got the method

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
    By.xpath("//table[@class='TextObject']//tr//td[contains(text(),'16 Weeks Historical Trend')]")));
 and its not working in my case