# Katalon studio Unable to set text (Root cause: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

Hi guys i am using katalon studio and whiling passing text via set text email to email input field  i am getting this issue:

```
Test Cases/Valid_Login FAILED because (of) Unable to set text 'usman@myfake.tk' of object 'Object Repository/Page_Webtalk  Communicate Better/input_email' (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
System info: host: 'USMAN', ip: '192.168.11.206', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.firefox.CGeckoDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 58.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 5508, moz:profile: C:\Users\usmanPC\AppData\Lo..., moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 6.3, proxy: Proxy(direct), rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: d28ee92a-cfee-47ad-b6a2-46c705493a4e)

Test Cases/Valid_Login.run:31
```

Generated code is below:

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory as CheckpointFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as MobileBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory as TestCaseFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory as TestDataFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository as ObjectRepository
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WSBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUiBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys as Keys

WebUI.openBrowser('')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://dev.webtalk.co/')

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Webtalk  Communicate Better/a_Login'))

WebUI.waitForElementPresent(findTestObject('Page_Webtalk  Communicate Better/input_email'), 5)

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_Webtalk  Communicate Better/input_email'), 'usman@myfake.tk')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_Webtalk  Communicate Better/input_login_password'), 'Pmasuaar1@#$')

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Webtalk  Communicate Better/input_login_button'))

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Webtalk  Communicate Better/button_Talk'))

WebUI.closeBrowser()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve ElementNotInteractableException in Selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: this question it self has not an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by adding a delay line (WebUI.delay(3)) before the call to the element that shows the error.