# Selenium select option from dropdown menu even when I am getting all the tags

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I trying to select size of shoe from this [website link](https://18montrose.com/collections/footwear-mens/products/common-projects-original-achilles-low-sneakers-in-grey-67comm1994gry). 
I tried almost all the ways like select, select_by_index, select_by_value etc but getting the following error -

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

My code looks like-

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
s1= Select(driver.find_element_by_name('id'))
s1.select_by_index(2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve ElementNotInteractableException in Selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: No, I am getting all the tags but unable to select or click on dropdown itms(like I want to select UK 7 in size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select element is disabled you need to handle drop-down unordered list:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Select Size").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[.='UK 6']").click()
```

If you want to select option by index:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='product-size-select-list']/li")[1].click()
```