# What does FindElement(By.ClassName("classname")) returns when "text" is not unique?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am very much displaying my ignorance here, but when a page has multiple elements with the same class name it seems like my code no longer interacts with the page in a predictable way. For example, if there is a single element on a page with class "submit" I can write:

```js
WebElement submitButton;
submitButton = bot.findElement(By.className("submit"));
submitButton.click();
```

And that submit button will be clicked in the browser. But, if on that same webpage there are two (or more) elements with class "home", I could write:

```js
WebElement homeButton;
homeButton = bot.findElement(By.className("home"));
homeButton.click();
```

And it seems nothing is clicked on.

Comment: probably returns and array of elements with that class. have you tried console logging what it returns to see?

Comment: There might be elements with class home located in the DOM and being hidden. You script tries to click them but nothing would happen in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Just like `findElement(By.id(java.lang.String id))` or `findElement(By.name(java.lang.String name))`, **`findElement(By.className(java.lang.String className))`** would also return you the first matching element on the *Web Page*.

### By.className("submit")

As you mentioned that there is a single element present in the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) with *class* **submit**, hence your [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) will always find the unique element and your subsequent `click()` would work well.

### By.className("home")

As you mentioned that there are two (or more) elements with *class* **home** in the *HTML DOM*, so the  *Locator Strategy* within the line `bot.findElement(By.className("home"));` will pickup the first matching element present in the [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) irrespective of the conditions if the element is **visible**, **displayed**, **intercatable** or not. Hence your subsequent `click()` may even fail.

### Impact

In such cases you may be facing either of the following exceptions:

- [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv/44724688#44724688)
- [ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-in-selenium-webdriver/46601444#46601444)

### Solution

- Instead of **`By.className("home")`** you can use either of the following:

  - [**`By.cssSelector(java.lang.String selector)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#cssSelector-java.lang.String-)
  - [**`By.xpath(java.lang.String xpathExpression)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#xpath-java.lang.String-)
  - If your *AUT* is *JavaScript* / *Ajax* based you may even need to induce a waiter through [WebDriverwait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [Excepted Conditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)