# How to resolve ElementNotInteractableException thrown by sendKeys method of Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

As an exercise in learning Selenium WebDriver I am trying to visit the [Twitter log in page](https://twitter.com/login?lang=en) and log in. I am finally able to navigate to the page and get the desired* element for the username field:

`<input class="text-input email-input js-signin-email" name="session[username_or_email]" type="text">`

*I have tried to find what types of elements `sendKeys` operates with but I can't. I think this element is the one I want since the tag is of the `<input>` type.

When I call `sendKeys` on the element after assigning it I get an `ElementNotInteractableException`. I have tried using explicit waits with the `ExpectedConditions` of `visibilityOf` and `invisibilityOf`. The respective interpretation of the `TimeoutException` and `ElementNotInteractableException` tells me that the element I mentioned above loads in the DOM tree but never becomes visible*. How do I get around this? Is there a solution using a `JavascriptExecutor`?

*The surrounding html might reveal why the element remains invisible:

```
<form class="t1-form clearfix signin js-signin"
action="https://twitter.com/sessions" method="post">
  ::before
  <fieldset>
    <legend class="visuallyhidden">Log in</legend>
    <div class="clearfix field">
      ::before
      <input class="text-input email-input js-signin-email"
      name="session[username_or_email]" type="text">
```

.

**For those on the hunt, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-in-selenium-webdriver) question is helpful to look at especially if the issue is caused by the `click` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test  {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://twitter.com/login?lang=en");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    // locate login input
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder = 'Phone, email or username']")));
    WebElement loginInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder = 'Phone, email or username']"));
    loginInput.click();
    loginInput.sendKeys("login");

    // locate password input
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//fieldset//input[@placeholder = 'Password']")));
    WebElement passInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//fieldset//input[@placeholder = 'Password']")); // this xPath does the trick
    passInput.click();
    passInput.sendKeys("password");
    Thread.sleep(3000); // only to see the result

    //locate submit button
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@type= 'submit']")));
    WebElement submitBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type= 'submit']"));
    submitBtn.click();

    Thread.sleep(3000); // only to see the result
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it a good practice/necessary to use `click` before `sendKeys`?

Comment: Lastly is `JavascriptExecutor` more expensive to use and/or a last resort?

Comment: Turns out I was trying to locate using `By.name` and there were multiples. `By.xpath` reigns supreme. Thank you.

Comment: It's necessary to use click before sendKeys. JavascriptExecutor is also possible and not expencive, but if you can do something easy in Java, there is no point to use JavascriptExecutor.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: apparently I didn't do quite enough research, although I didn't see this question on StackOverflow. Going to leave this question in case it helps someone.

Using `JavascriptExecutor` (Source 1.):

1. Import: `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;`
2. General idea: `JavascriptExecutor executor= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   executor.executeScript(script, arguments);`
3. For a `sendKeys` alternative we need to execute a bit of JS that sets the text value of the element using dot notation. We have to find the element first. (Source 1.) Use `document.getElementById('id')`, `document.getElementsByTagName('name')`, or `document.getElementsByClassName('class')` to find the element (Source 2.). Note that for the last two options for locating the element multiple elements are gathered, so index the one you want.

An example line of code that turned out to be my solution:
`executor.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('js-username-field email-input js-initial-focus')[0].value='someValue';");`

Note that `.getElementById('id')` is probably preferred, but in my case the website designers decided to be uncooperative and not provide an id attribute.

Here are two (incredible!) resources on the subject--check them out!

1. https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/javascriptexecutor-selenium-webdriver/
2. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp

Comment: There is no need in `JavascriptExecutor` in your case, just use `xPath` I have provided, it works.