# Getting ElementNotInteractableException while using Choose File command in robot framework only with firefox version 62.0

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

After updating to firefox 62.0, getting Getting ElementNotInteractableException for CHoose File command.

The same code worked for previous firefox version and in Chrome.

Request to provide a fix to run the script in latest firefox version. Thank You

Comment: Please give us more details. For example the versions of `geckodriver`, SeleniumLibrary, Selenium. Also this question is probably already asked and answered.

Comment: Please find my versions below: robotframework-seleniumlibrary  - 3.1.1 ; geckodriver 0.21.0. Firefox browser version: 62.0. With Firefox browser version 57 and gecko driver - 0.20.0 i was able to upload files with Choose File command. After updating my Firefox browser im facing ElementNotInteractableException issue

Comment: Well, there may be a different speed on having the element accessible. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-in-selenium-webdriver there is a proposal to add some Sleep before trying to interact. You should add the `Wait Until Element is Visible` or other `Wait ...` keywords before calling `Choose File`. It is a known difficulty to manage tests when there are updates of tools or browsers versions.