# Webdriver won't click "Accept cookies" button, throws "ElementNotInteractable" Exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium3

First of all, I'm using Cucumber 4.2 and Selenium 3 on Firefox 64.

I'm trying to get past the "Accept cookies" button with Selenium, but nothing seems to work. I've tried following [DebanjanB's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601444/4650392) to this error, but without any luck.

Here's my code:

```
String btnLocation = new String("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div");
WebDriverWait wait15 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait15.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(btnLocation)));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(btnLocation)).click();
```

And this is the error trace:

```
    And I have accepted the cookies                     # Stepdefs.i_have_accepted_the_cookies()
  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <div class="optanon-alert-box-button-middle accept-cookie-container"> could not be scrolled into view
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KS4A1NQ', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '9'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 64.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 28204, moz:profile: C:\Users\cian\AppData\Loca..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 30433d1c-d85b-45d6-b65e-076d3e04f3ec
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
        at [org_name].cucumber_ex.Stepdefs.i_have_accepted_the_cookies(Stepdefs.java:55)
        at ?.I have accepted the cookies([org_name]/cucumber_ex/Navigate_Menu_Categories.feature:26)

    When I roll my mouse over a category                # Stepdefs.i_roll_my_mouse_over_a_category()
    And the dropdown menu appears                       # Stepdefs.the_dropdown_menu_appears()
    And I click a subcategory                           # Stepdefs.i_click_a_subcategory()
    Then I should be brought to that subcategory's page # Stepdefs.i_should_be_brought_to_that_subcategory_s_page()

Failed scenarios:
[org_name]/cucumber_ex/Navigate_Menu_Categories.feature:24 # User wants to pick a product category

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
6 Steps (1 failed, 4 skipped, 1 passed)
0m8.878s

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <div class="optanon-alert-box-button-middle accept-cookie-container"> could not be scrolled into view
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KS4A1NQ', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '9'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 64.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 28204, moz:profile: C:\Users\cian\AppData\Loca..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 30433d1c-d85b-45d6-b65e-076d3e04f3ec
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
        at [org_name].cucumber_ex.Stepdefs.i_have_accepted_the_cookies(Stepdefs.java:55)
        at ?.I have accepted the cookies([org_name]/cucumber_ex/Navigate_Menu_Categories.feature:26)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.104 sec <<< FAILURE!
User wants to pick a product category(Navigate menu categories)  Time elapsed: 8.748 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <div class="optanon-alert-box-button-middle accept-cookie-container"> could not be scrolled into view
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KS4A1NQ', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '9'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 64.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 28204, moz:profile: C:\Users\cian\AppData\Loca..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 30433d1c-d85b-45d6-b65e-076d3e04f3ec
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
        at [org_name].cucumber_ex.Stepdefs.i_have_accepted_the_cookies(Stepdefs.java:55)
        at ?.I have accepted the cookies([org_name]/cucumber_ex/Navigate_Menu_Categories.feature:26)


Results :

Tests in error:
  User wants to pick a product category(Navigate menu categories): Element <div class="optanon-alert-box-button-middle accept-cookie-container"> could not be scrolled into view(..)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.302 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-11T12:41:05Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project cucumber-ex: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\cian\Documents\GitHub\Cucumber-Assignment\cucumber-ex\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project cucumber-ex: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\cian\Documents\GitHub\Cucumber-Assignment\cucumber-ex\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\cian\Documents\GitHub\Cucumber-Assignment\cucumber-ex\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution (SurefireHelper.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.writeSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:650)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:586)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

I tried changing the third line of my code to:

```
List<WebElement> elList = wait15.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(btnLocation)));
System.out.println("Elements found: " + elList.size());
for(WebElement el : elList) {
System.out.println(el.toString());
}
```

...to make sure that element existed, and it did.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I should add, I used "Inspect element" to get the Xpath of the "Accept cookies" button. I've also tried copying that button's class, but when I search for that class in the webpage's source code, not even the word "accept" can be found in it, let alone the class name.

**EDIT 2.0**
To answer Recep's comment, here's the button's HTML:

```
<div class="optanon-alert-box-button-middle accept-cookie-container" style="">
<a class="optanon-allow-all accept-cookies-button" title="Accepter les cookies" aria-label="Accepter les cookies" role="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Optanon.TriggerGoogleAnalyticsEvent('OneTrust Cookie Consent', 'Banner Accept Cookies');" tabindex="3">Accepter les cookies</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML section of this button?

Comment: @RecepDuman Sure, I've added it to my question now.

Comment: Can you try the following code? `driver.findElement(By.className("optanon-allow-all accept-cookies-button")).click();`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Recep, but now I get this error: `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .optanon\-allow\-all\ accept\-cookies\-button`

Answer (score 0):

the exception states "could not be scrolled into view".  when you run it, do you actually see the target button on screen?  have you tried adding a step to scroll the item into view?  I don't know how to do that with java and cucumber, but with python it's something like:

```
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button_element_to_click)
```

Comment: Yes, I can see the target button.

Comment: `scrollIntoView()` the **Accept cookies** button?

Comment: I've tried that, but the button doesn't get clicked.

Comment: what is the error you get when you attempt the click after scrolling into view?

Comment: I get told that `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <div class="optanon-alert-box-button optanon-button-allow"> could not be scrolled into view`, I've tried scrolling both the button and the cookie alert into view but neither work

Comment: my only thought at the moment is that there are multiple buttons matching that btnLocation and so it's trying to click a different one than the one you're actually seeing.  is your elList more than one item?

Comment: No, it just contains 1. I used "Inspect Element" on the "Accept cookies" button so I could copy its Xpath for fetching any elements with said Xpath, and every time only the "Accept cookies" button would correspond to that.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use OneTrust.AllowAll()