# Sending keys to autocomplete text box

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

There is an autocomplete text box in a web page I am trying to read from. I would like to click the text box and enter certain text into it and click the associated name but I am encountering this error message:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

This is what I have written

```
page_link = 'http://beta.compuboxdata.com/fighter'
chromedriver = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver'
cdriver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
cdriver.get(page_link)
cdriver.find_element_by_class_name('select2-chosen').send_keys('Deontay Wilder')
```

This is what the site looks like

The keys should presumably be sent to id-'select2-chosen'

Sending the keys to this id returns the error message:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="select2-chosen1"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni) might solve your issue.

Comment: @Saravanan not sure the answers in that question are helping

Comment: It seems that you are getting the class name of the `span` inside the search instead of `input` element. Use `cdriver.find_element_by_id('s2id_autogen1').send_keys('Deontay Wilder')`. It will correctly send text to search.

Comment: @Emm I think this is not a duplicate question. Someone just marked Duplicate without looking at the question properly.

Comment: @TekNath I agree

Comment: @Emm could you share the url?

Comment: url is in the variable page_link. TekNath's comment/answer worked

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to send keys to the span element.

I think you want to click on the span, then enter text into the input element.