# WebDriver not detecting input textbox, throws ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I've written some code to send input to a textbox as shown below :

[image]

[image]

[image]
However during execution, the webdriver returns ElementNotInteractableException even though it shows the input type is a textbox.

I've tried to send input using the following ways but have been unsuccessful, seeking advice, thanks!:

1)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='bkg_no']")).sendKeys("ABCDE9000333");
```

2)

```
String bkg = "ABCDE9000333"
WebElement bkgNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='bkg_no']"));";
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value="+bkg+";", bkgNo);
```

3)

```
driver.findElement(By.name("bkg_no")).sendKeys("ABCDE9000333");
```

4)

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;    
jse.executeScript("document.getElementByName('bkg_no').value='PKG900890300'");
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601444/1230748

Comment: I tried using the wait() methods you've described in that post, it still does not work, I did notice when I use excecuteScript(), the code runs without any exceptions but nothing is inputted into the textbox

`Code WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='bkg_no']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element); executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='ABCDE90003330';",element);
`

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the `<input>` you have to induce WebDriverWait for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("form[name='form'][onkeydown*='search'] div.wrap_search input.input[name='bkg_no']"))).sendKeys("ABCDE9000333");
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//form[@name='form' and contains(@onkeydown, 'search')]//div[contains(@class, 'wrap_search')]//input[@class='input' and @name='bkg_no']"))).sendKeys("ABCDE9000333");
  ```

Comment: This did not seem to work, the element can only be somehow found by its relative xpath //input[@name='bkg_no'] . The weird thing is when I use the selenium IDE addon in chrome, its able to find the inputbox by name and when I playback the recording, it seems to work successfully, no idea why :/