# Unable to upload a pdf file using send_keys or requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using selenium to log in to a website and then go on to the target page in order to upload a pdf file. The script can log in successfully but throws `element not interactable` error when it comes to upload the pdf file. This is the [landing_page](https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/SEARCH/RESULTS/) in which the script first clicks on the button right next to `Your Profile` and uses `SIM.iqbal_123` and `SShift_123` respectively to log in to that site and then uses this [target_link](https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/APPLICATION/57274787/2/) to upload that file. To upload that file it is necessary to click on `select` button first and then `cv` button. However, the script throws the following error when it is supposed to click on the `cv` button in order to upload the `pdf` file.

I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

landing_page = 'https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/SEARCH/RESULTS/'
target_link = 'https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/APPLICATION/57274787/2/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

driver.get(landing_page)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".profileContainer > button.trigger"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='alias']"))).send_keys("SIM.iqbal_123")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='password']"))).send_keys("SShift_123")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.loginBtn"))).click()

driver.get(target_link)
button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[class*='uploadBtn']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",button)
elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"form[class='fileForm'] > label[data-type='12']")))
elem.send_keys("C://Users/WCS/Desktop/CV.pdf")
```

Error that the script encounters pointing at the last line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\keep_it.py", line 22, in <module>
    elem.send_keys("C://Users/WCS/Desktop/CV.pdf")
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

This is how I tried using requests which could not upload the file either:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

aplication_link = 'https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/opu/odata/hcmx/erc_ui_auth_srv/AttachmentSet?sap-client=100&sap-language=en'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.auth = ("SIM.iqbal_123", "SShift_123")
    s.post("https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/hcmx/validate_ea?sap-client=100&sap-language={2}")
    r = s.get("https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/opu/odata/hcmx/erc_ui_auth_srv/UserSet('me')?sap-client=100&sap-language=en", headers={'x-csrf-token':'Fetch'})

    token = r.headers.get("x-csrf-token")
    s.headers["x-csrf-token"] = token

    file = open("CV.pdf","rb")
    r = s.post(aplication_link,files={"Slug":f"Filename={file}&Title=CV%5FTEST&AttachmentTypeID=12"})
    print(r.status_code)
```

Btw, this is the [pdf](https://filebin.net/dc41y5p7ix8jp58t) file in case you wanna test.

> How can I upload a pdf file using send_keys or requests?

***EDIT:***

I've brought about some changes in my [existing script](https://filebin.net/r4ux62fizvyu29ne) which now works for this [link](https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/APPLICATION/57274787/1/) visible there as `Cover Letter` but fails miserably when it goes for this [link](https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/APPLICATION/57274787/2/) visible as `Documents` . They both are almost identical.

Comment: you want to send keys to the <input> tag with a type of "file".

Comment: don't click the browse button, just send keys.

Comment: The click was meant for the `select` button to unveil the `cv` button which is hidden. However, the file gets uploaded when I click on the `cv` button and choose the file.

Comment: try element.send_keys, and then element.submit()... this may or may not work... it depends on how much they rely on javascript for submission.  If that doesn't work post the markup/scripts used.

Comment: I assumed that error was because you had a file browse dialog open.  Post current code trials and markup + script(s).

Comment: Check out the edit. Btw, this is my current script.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below solution to avoid your exception,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import os


landing_page = 'https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/SEARCH/RESULTS/'
target_link = 'https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/APPLICATION/57262231/2/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

driver.get(landing_page)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".profileContainer > button.trigger"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='alias']"))).send_keys("SIM.iqbal_123")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='password']"))).send_keys("SShift_123")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.loginBtn"))).click()

driver.get(target_link)
driver.maximize_window()
button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[class*='uploadBtn']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",button)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label[@class='button uploadType-12-btn']")))
print element.text
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
absolute_file_path = os.path.abspath("Path of your pdf file")

print absolute_file_path
file_input = driver.find_element_by_id("DOCUMENTS--fileElem")
file_input.send_keys(absolute_file_path)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Your script works partially @Rock. I executed your script and could notice that it does upload the file but again open the window (through which the files get uploaded) for the second time and gets stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script , it upload document on both pages

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

landing_page = 'https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/SEARCH/RESULTS/'
first_target_link = 'https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/APPLICATION/57274787/1/'
second_target_link = 'https://jobs.allianz.com/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zhcmx_erc_ui_ex/desktop.html#/APPLICATION/57274787/2/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

driver.get(landing_page)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".profileContainer > button.trigger"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='alias']"))).send_keys("SIM.iqbal_123")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='password']"))).send_keys("SShift_123")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.loginBtn"))).click()

#----------------------------first upload starts from here-----------------------------------
driver.get(first_target_link)

button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[class*='uploadBtn']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",button) 

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"form[class='fileForm'] > label[class$='uploadTypeCoverLetterBtn']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)

file_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[id='COVERLETTER--fileElem")))
file_input.send_keys("C://Users/WCS/Desktop/script selenium/CV.pdf")

wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".loadingSpinner")))

save_draft = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".applicationStepsUIWrapper > button.saveDraftBtn")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",save_draft)
close = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".promptWrapper button.closeBtn")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",close)
#-------------------------second upload starts from here-------------------------------------
driver.get(second_target_link)

button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[class*='uploadBtn']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",button)

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"form[class='fileForm'] > label[data-type='12']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)

file_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[id='DOCUMENTS--fileElem")))
file_input.send_keys("C://Users/WCS/Desktop/script selenium/CV.pdf")

wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".loadingSpinner")))

save_draft = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".applicationStepsUIWrapper > button.saveDraftBtn")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",save_draft)
close = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".promptWrapper button.closeBtn")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",close)
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the script that I've already shown in my post as `existing script` and the one you have proposed here except for using `driver.execute_script()` @Bhargav Desai? It's not working btw.

Comment: Is there problem ?? when i run script, it upload document on both page properly.