# Trying to click radio buttons using Selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a button using selenium, i have attached an image of the html code.

so far i have:

```
  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][id='SF_SP2_01']").click()
```

but get error saying:

```
   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try using Actions Class to click the element?

Answer (score 0):

[First, see if the advice in this link helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni)

However, if that does not help, the element you are trying to click may not be in the same frame you are currently in. Check for any < iframe> tags in the html, and if there is one the fix should be something simple like:

`driver.switch_to.frame('iframe_here')`

Then you will be able to interact with the element.

That is one possible solution, it may not be the correct one for this issue but give it a try.