# ElementNotInteractableException Thrown While Selecting Value From Select Tag

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, automation

This is the DOM structure.
[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe3ZF.png)

Any of the following operations are throwing `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException`

```
selectFileStatus.selectByIndex(2);
```

Or

```
selectFileStatus.selectByVisibleText(valueToSelect);
```

The instantiation is like this.

```
Select selectFileStatus = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(
                property.getPropertyObject(propFileDetailClaimReview).getProperty(propertyDropdownFileStatus)))));
```

And the XPATH is tested in browser.

```
//span[contains(text(), 'File Status')]/parent::label/following-sibling::select
```

Interestingly, a read operation is working fine.

```
List<WebElement> allOptions = selectFileStatus.getOptions();
System.out.println("*** Values of the dropdown...");
for(WebElement eachOption : allOptions)
    System.out.println(eachOption.getText());
```

As this `<select>` tag looks like a real HTML object, what can be the problem here?

Note: Tried JS injection, and it did nothing actually (I expected it to expand the dropdown).

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                property.getPropertyObject(propFileDetailClaimReview).getProperty(propertyDropdownFileStatus)));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

Comment: Do you get any more detail in the error message? Have you had a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni/46601444

Comment: @Jocke Yes, I had :) This is the error I got - org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'. So, nothing about invisible element here. :)

Comment: Did you try using a JS executor ?

Comment: @WilfredClement Yes, I did. This code didn't work for me (I wanted to click and expand the dropdown). WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(     property.getPropertyObject(propFileDetailClaimReview).getProperty(propertyDropdownFileStatus)));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);