# Error "ElementNotInteractableException" while login in a website using Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've wrote this script to login into Nike website, I get an `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException` error  because of pop-up message in the website when I try to login, I tried differents approches but nothing worked, here's my code :

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

r = requests.get('https://www.nike.com/fr/launch?s=in-stock')

url = 'https://www.nike.com/fr/launch/t/air-max-90-pink-foam'

#accountINFO
uid = 'sss@gmail.com'
pwd = 'XXXX'


#boost browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '//Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
mcookis = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-qa='accept-cookies']")
mcookis.click()
time.sleep(1)

memberLogin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-qa='top-nav-join-or-login-button']")
memberLogin.click()
time.sleep(1)

#Login
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")
elem.send_keys(uid)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
login_submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='CONNEXION']")
#time.sleep(1)
login_submit.click()
```

normally after submit is run I should access the site but instead I get an error message, when I type the pswd manually it's working.

Comment: Please share the full traceback

Comment: @Arount I added a picture of Pop-up message.

Comment: Which element is failing?

Comment: In the `login_submit ` part @WojtekT normally after submit I should access the site but instead I get an error message, when I type the pswd manually it's working

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle Webdriver wait to get visible of element

Comment: Can you explain how ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni this link will help you to resolve this

Comment: It's not python ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've got your problem.
If the problem is the pop up, just use selenium to close it clicking on 'close' or 'x' and then search for the login button.
Be also sure to wait some seconds before searching a new element, e.g.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]').click(), time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: my problem is that when I try to login I get an error with a pop up that I want to close automaticlly but Can't figure out how to do it this is the full xpath for the error I want to close : `/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div[2]/input`

Comment: Clicking manually on the popup do you get access to the site?
The problem is that you can't click the popup? Try looking the path while using interactive window.

Comment: Yes it's working manually @Ischio