# Compound class names not permitted - Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, ant, webdriver

I have following button to locate. It is an ant controller.

```xml
<li class="ant-picker-ok"><button type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary ant-btn-sm"><span>Ok</span></button></li>
```

this is located in data entry form and its XPath change depend upon the selections that we made in top part of the form. So XPath cannot use. then i tried CSS selector and it also not support.

Finally I used class name as location strategy and use move to element.

```java
@FindBy(className = "ant-picker-ok")
public WebElement shiftEndOkBtn;
```

code successfully execute upto below line.

```java
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(shiftEndOkBtn).perform();
```

clicking part us not working and throws element is not visible. But element is visible

```java
shiftEndOkBtn.click();
```

This is a ant time picker(**https://ant.design/components/time-picker/**)Any idea to solve this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking the 'li' element, not the button. Try find it by XPath:

```
//li[@class = 'ant-picker-ok']/button
```

Comment: That xpath is not working.