# Unable to click element using selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click the search box where "Search for a company" is written in the webpage (webpage inspect element screenshot below ) using Selenium WebDriver in python and want to send some text to that search box. I have written below code:

```
yourOption = selenium_webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='search']")
yourOption.send_keys("532005"
time.sleep(1)
yourOption.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
time.sleep(1)
yourOption.send_keys(Keys.RETURN))
```

I am getting following exception:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
```

Here is the screenshot of inspect element of webpage.

[image]

Can somebody please help?

Comment: what happens if you send to `div.search` css locator

Comment: I'd like to refer you to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601444/6845383

Comment: Is my argument that I am passing to find_element_by_css_selector correct?

Comment: Is there any way to know if WebElement is under Temporary Overlay or Permanent Overlay?