# ElementNotInteractableException using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I'm trying to enter some text into a field, it works for the first time but after that, it shows this error! `ElementNotInteractableException` I don't know why!
here you are my code:

```
try:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,600)", "")
    WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))
    comment = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//XPATH")
    comment.send_keys(comments)
```

Comment: Here you are my code:

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601444/1387701

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the element instead of `visibility_of_element_located()` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
try:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,600)", "")
    WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, path)))
    comment = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//XPATH")
    comment.send_keys(comments)
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```